# vsftpd not working with FileZilla

Tags: server, permissions, ftp, vsftpd

I have been trying to use VSFTPD with my server that I host on Vultr.

All seems to be working, doing `nano file.php` and creating the file within the folder will work perfectly fine and appear on the website.

However, whenever I upload with FileZilla everything seems to be working fine, until I actually try and view that file on the website. I get a `HTTP ERROR 500` which seems odd.

I had to turn off passive mode as I couldn't upload with this on and I have the correct permissions on the folder and everything seems to be fine but when uploading with passive mode enabled it appears that the I get a critical error.

```
pas_min_port=40000
pas_max_port=50000
```

Answer (score 0):

The following site describes some reasons for [HTTP 500 errors](https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938).

One reason which seems to be the problem in your case is wrong permission which was set by the FTP server.

I'd suggest to log-in the server, and perform `ls -lsa` on the file which was uploaded by the FTP client, and also on the file which you were creating using `nano file.php` if the file permission is different, please change the file permission of the file uploaded by FTP-client, and check again if it works.

If you don't know which file permission should be used, I'd suggest using:

```
chmod 755 file-name
```

> **Fixing 500 Internal Server Error Problems on Your Own Site**
>
> A 500 Internal Server Error on your own website requires a completely
>   different course of action. As I mentioned above, most 500 errors are
>   server-side errors, meaning it's likely your problem to fix if it's
>   your website.
>
> There are lots of reasons why your site might be serving a 500 Error
>   to your users, but two are most common:
>
> **A Permissions Error.** In most cases, a 500 Internal Server Error is due to an incorrect permission on one or more files or folders. In
>   most of those cases, **an incorrect permission on a PHP and CGI script
>   is to blame. These should usually be set at 0755 (-rwxr-xr-x)**.